# Passing PHP array in Javascript function as argument

Tags: javascript, arrays, arguments

I am getting error with the following code

```
    $string.="<input class='jt-test-question-answer-choice-radio' name='q1' type='$input' value='q20a1' onclick=\"correct_answer1(\"$correctanswer\",'$row1[1]')\";/>";
```

$correctanswer is an array having value "test2,test4";  I have used implode function to split the array and then in the js function I have used split.When clicked the function is not calling.

Comment: Check your outputted HTML and you may find out: you're using double quote both _on_ and _in_ the `onclick` property.

Comment: Check the outputted HTML. Also, is $correctanswer an array or a string?

Comment: I am not able to check output as the page is an Ajax page.$correctanswer value is "test2,test4" ie I have used implode of array and I get the value like this to pass it in javascript function

Comment: To check output in chrome - after the input element is visible right click it and select 'Inspect element'. Then right click click the element in Developer tools and select 'Copy as HTML'. As for your problem, try changing `onclick` value to `\"correct_answer1('$correctanswer','$row1[1]')\"`